# pass value of the dataset sas to a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

i'm learning sas macro language but i have a problem
i wrote a macro:

```
%macro avg_acceleration(mark_type, avg_acceleration, mark_angle);
%if &mark_type='A' %then %sysfunc(abs(&avg_acceleration/%sysfunc(cos(%sysfunc(abs(&mark_angle*( 3.1415926535897/180.0)))))));
%else %if &mark_type='C' %then %sysfunc(abs(&avg_acceleration/%sysfunc(sin(%sysfunc(abs(&mark_angle*( 3.1415926535897/180.0)))))));
%mend avg_acceleration;
```

then what i want to do is launch a macro in another macro :

```
%macro statistiche;
data pippo;
set prova;
a = mark_type;
b= avg_acceleration;
c = mark_angle;
avg_acc=%avg_acceleration(a, b, c);
run;
%mend statistiche;

%statistiche;
```

but i have this error:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, INPUT, PUT.
```

Is not possible use the macro in this way?? What is the right way to do what i want??? Thank you

Comment: You're combining data step and macro language in a way it shouldn't be.  Macro language writes code to be then executed by the data step; it shouldn't execute the functions itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want 2 macros to do this.  Why not just a simple data step?

```
data work.test;
set work.prova;
if mark_type='A' then do;
    avg_acc=abs(avg_acceleration)/(cos(abs(mark_angle)*(constant('pi')/180.0)));
end;
if mark_type='C' then do;
    avg_acc=abs(avg_acceleration)/(sin(abs(mark_angle)*(constant('pi')/180.0)));
end;
run;
```

Comment: yes you are right but i want to do that with another macro to reuse the code in another data steps

Comment: Then just take my code above, turn it into a macro and pass it 2 variables -- dataset in and dataset out.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative data step with less repetitive code:

```
data work.test;
  set work.prova;
  select (mark_type);
    when('A') phase = 0;
    when('C') phase = 90;
  end;
  avg_acc=abs(avg_acceleration)/cos((mark_angle + phase)*constant('pi')/180.0);
run;
```

If you wanted to capture this logic for reuse in other data steps with the option to use different data set variables in place of the original ones, you could do something like this:

```
%macro avg_acceleration(mark_type        =mark_type,
                        avg_acceleration =avg_acceleration,
                        mark_angle       =mark_angle,
                        avg_acc          =avg_acc
                       );
      select (&mark_type);
        when('A') phase = 0;
        when('C') phase = 90;
      end;
      &avg_acc=abs(&avg_acceleration)/cos((&mark_angle + phase)*constant('pi')/180.0);
%mend;
```

Then you should be able to call it or less as you originally expected:

```
data work.test;
  set work.prova;
  %avg_acceleration;
run;
```

Comment: why you add phase to mark_angle? Could you explain the reason? Anyway I try to run your avg_acceleration macro but the result is not correct.

Comment: Sorry - as a maths graduate, it's been such a long time since I used trig functions with degrees rather than radians that I forgot that I needed to specify the phase in degrees. It works now.

Comment: This is using a couple of identities to simplify the expression - `cos(x + pi/2) = sin(x)` saves a line and `cos(x) = cos(-x)` to avoid using `abs()`.

Comment: sorry, I had not yet seen